# Running new Android Studio Project restarts Windows 8.1 (Bad Pool Caller Error)

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-8.1

I've been using Eclipse + ADT for Android Developement. I just started with Android Studio and created the simplest "My Application" project. But when I run the Project every time a blue Screen Covers the whole screen saying the occurrence of **Bad Pool Caller Error** and restarts the Computer.

I'm using

- windows 8.1
- Android Studio 1.0
- Ram 2 GB

Comment: That seems not Android related at all. I personally would fix it by installing Linux, but you might as well try to sort out the Windows issue (probably start by updating all drivers). If that's on a emulator try with a real device. Also make sure you have the latest Android SDK.

Comment: I'm using Real android device, and also the SDK is up to date. Android Studio is also upto date. I downloaded it less than 10 hours ago from Official site.

Comment: A blue screen is frequently driver related and sometimes a physical hardware failure (e.g. bad RAM); check for driver updates from your PC/motherboard manufacturer.

Comment: Google the error message,it all links to some hardcore Windows stuff (as in: "This is a bad pool call" and a hex dump), nothing points to Android, nothing to Intellij / Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guys mentioned in comments that its a Windows problem. I think that I sort of sorted it out! Though not the right way.
I'm using Avast Antivirus. I disabled it for an hour and Ran the Project. The project ran fine. And even after I enabled avast, Android Studio is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess...the last time I checked. Android Studio was on a beta version, which means it might have some compatibility issues. You must be using a beta version...if so that maybe your problem.

Comment: Nope. I'm using Latest stable release of Android studio that I downloaded from official site less than 10 hours ago